# Web.contents power query reference cell

Tags: excel, powerquery, excel-external-data, vba

Please have a look at the following code

```
Source = *Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/20MICRONS.NS/history?p=20MICRONS.NS"")*)
```

For the italics text i.e. the hyperlink, I am trying to link it to a cell. Can anyone tell me how this can be done?

I tried using the Cells tag but in vain

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain what you are asking, but if you are saying that you want to replace "https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/20MICRONS.NS/history?p=20MICRONS.NS" with a URL from a column, and bring in that URL's info, you might try `Web.Page(Web.Contents([Custom]))`, where [Custom] is the column with the URLs you want to use. This will embed a table of information for each URL listed in the "Custom" column, in that URL's corresponding row.

For instance, if the column "Custom" has https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/20MICRONS.NS/history?p=20MICRONS.NS in it, like this:

[image]

...then creating a new column with `Web.Page(Web.Contents([Custom]))` would embed this table:

[image]

...in the new column, like this:

[image]

Expanding the new column (in this case, "Custom1") would give you something like this:

[image]

And expanding the "Data" column would give you something like this:

[image]

I believe the info in "Column1.1" and "Column2" is what you are after from the URL you provided.

[image]

---

**An edit following our comment discussion is below**

Using Excel 2016, I set up a worksheet with the URL in column B, like you said yours is. Like this:

[image]

Then I click in either cell A1 or B1, and then I click the "Data" tab and the button to create a query from a table:

[image]

...which gives me this:

[image]

...and I click "OK", which gives me this in the Power Query Editor:

[image]

Then I click the "Add Column" tab and "Custom Column" button...

[image]

...and fill out the pop-up screen like this:

[image]

...and click "OK"...which gives me this:

[image]

Then I click the button at the top right of the "Custom" column...[image]...to expand the tables in the "Custom" column and get this:

[image]

Then I click the button at the top right of the "Data" column...[image]...to expand the tables in the "Data" column and get this:

[image]

Here's my query code:

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Web.Page(Web.Contents([Column2]))),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Caption", "Source", "ClassName", "Id", "Data"}, {"Caption", "Source", "ClassName", "Id", "Data"}),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded Custom", "Data", {"Column1", "Column2"}, {"Column1.1", "Column2.1"})
in
#"Expanded Data"
```

Comment: I think what you wrote is amazing. But I would be really grateful if you can help with that [custom] column step. I am unable to locate that.
I will try to write down my steps.
1. Copy the link from the cell
2. Click on Data-->Get Data--->From Web ---> Paste the URL
3. Click on Table 2 in the Navigator ... Display Options
4. Click on edit and keep only columns 1 and 4 (Date and Close)
5. Transpose the data and select first row as headers
6. Load the data to cell C1 (Column A contains the stock codes, column B contains the corresponding URLs)

Comment: I'm assuming you have a table with a column that has different URLs in it. If so, what is the name of that column?

Comment: The URLs are in column B of the excel sheet. I am trying to automate the get data from web process wherein data from all the urls in column b are scraped and pasted on to destinations in the same sheet using some macro.

Comment: When you get your data from your spreadsheet, into Power Query, your column B of the Excel sheet will have a column name (maybe "Column2"). You would use that column's name in place of "Custom". So if your column's name is Column2 you'd type `Web.Page(Web.Contents([Column2]))` instead of Web.Page(Web.Contents([Custom])). Does that make sense?

Comment: I am getting an error like this now.
Expression.Error: There is an unknown identifier. Did you use the [field] shorthand for a _[field] outside of an 'each' expression?

Comment: What formula to put in custom column formula field ?

Comment: Manish, I added some more to my earlier answer, based on our discussion. I placed it below the earlier stuff. I essentially started over, from the beginning, by setting up a spreadsheet with the URL in column B; and step through everything I did. Lastly, I included the query code.